# Bootstrap 4 - Modal Dialog with Tabs - Drop Down Menu

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am working in Bootstrap 4 and I have created a Modal Dialog Box.  I want the last link on the Modal Dialog Box to be a dropdown menu, but I can't seem to get the code just right.

My HTML, CSS and JQuery code can be found here at JSFiddle:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#AAA" data-toggle="tab">
                                AAA
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#BBB" data-toggle="tab">
                                BBB
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#CCC" data-toggle="tab">
                                CCC
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="DDL" href="#DDL">
                        Menu
                      </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#News">
                              News
                           </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the `href="..."` set to an element that doesn't exist (#DDL). Just remove it and it will find the next `dropdown-menu`.

```
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">
                    Menu
                  </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#News">
                          News
                       </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
       </li>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/nbXb8ipmxl